# insmod: failed to load /vendor/lib/modules/circular-char.ko (AOSP-barbet) (Pixel 5a)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-source, kernel-module

I am new with AOSP and inserting kernel modules.
I copied the module to /vendor/lib/modules/ on my phone and then tried to insmod, which is when I get the error.
I think I have made it against the correct kernel. What's the issue here? Can anyone help please?

`insmod: failed to load /vendor/lib/modules/circular-char.ko`

I am trying to insert a kernel module onto my Pixel 5a which is on AOSP android 13 for barbet. The kernel version- 4.19.269.gc19f689856e5-ab9801782.
The module is compiled against the repo branch android-msm-redbull-4.19-android13-qpr3. Got it from https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-kernels#id-version-from-aosp
To generate the .ko file, I placed my C code under /private/msm-google/drivers/char and made changes to the Makefile by adding

`obj -m += ciruclar-char.ko`

I then built the kernel (ran the build_redbull.sh script) and the .ko file was generated in /out/android-msm-pixel-4.19/dist
I checked demsg for logs but there is no mention of my module in there.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: insmod: failed to load /vendor/lib/modules/circular-char.ko: Exec format error @TimRoberts

Comment: I looked this error up and it says it's caused because of kernel version. But I think I have compiled it against the right kernel.